# Is there any way to zip files ignoring some names of the folders?

Tags: python, bash, zip, tar

I want to zip some PDFs. Right now they are in:

```
FolderA
├── 2022
│   ├── March
│   │   ├── PDF1 
│   │   ├── PDF2 
│   │   ├── PDF3
FolderB
├── 2022
│   ├── March
│   │   ├── PDF4 
│   │   ├── PDF5
```

I want my ZIP file to follow this structure:

```
zipname.zip
├── FolderA
│   ├── PDF1 
│   ├── PDF2 
│   ├── PDF3
├── FolderB
│   ├── PDF4
│   ├── PDF5
```

Is there any way to do this? So far, I found how to do it including the whole path or without any path at all (just the PDFs).

EDIT:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo What month do you want?
read month
mkdir "$month" || exit 1
cp -a FolderA/2022/"$month" "$month"/FolderA/
cp -a FolderB/2022/"$month" "$month"/FolderB/
zip -r $month$(date +%Y).zip "$month"/
rm -rf "$month"
```

Comment: @Cyrus sure, thanks :) and I think `tar` could help too

Comment: Please avoid adding an answer to your question and instead add an answer to your own question.

Comment: Note that your solution will create a totally different directory structure than specified by yourself.

Comment: I added my answer as an answer to the post but it was downvoted for some reason, so I thought that maybe I should include it into the OP. 

I don't know why you say it creates a totally different directory structure, the only thing that changes is the name of the zip file

Answer (score 2):

By using a short script you could create a temporary directory structure before compressing the files:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir tmp || exit 1
cp -a Folder* tmp/
cd tmp || exit 1
pwd
for dir in *
do
    cd $dir
    find . -type f -iname "*.pdf" -not -name "$dir" -exec mv {} ./ \;
    find . -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
    cd ..
done
cd ..
zip -r pdf.zip tmp/*
rm -rf tmp
```

Note that the `-exec rm -rf {}` part of find should be relatively safe, due to the script exiting if creating or changing to the `tmp` directory fails.

Comment: The thing is that I have other folders in each 2022 with PDFs on the other months (January and February), didn't include them in the first scheme so it's not too big, but it actually looks like this:

```
FolderA
├── 2022
│   ├── March
│   │   ├── PDF1 
│   │   ├── PDF2 
│   │   ├── PDF3
│   ├── January
│   │   ├── PDF10
│   │   ├── PDF11
│   ├── February
│   │   ├── PDF12
│   │   ├── PDF13
FolderB
├── 2022
│   ├── January
│   │   ├── PDF6 
│   │   ├── PDF7
│   ├── February
│   │   ├── PDF8
│   ├── March
│   │   ├── PDF4 
│   │   ├── PDF5
```

with other pdf names

Comment: @Alberto that doesn't matter. `find` will find each pdf file recursively and move them two directories up. The script is designed with that possibility in mind.

Comment: @Alberto you of course need to adjust the `cp` and the second `find` command with the actual names of your folders. You can specify multiple input folders with `cp` as only the last argument will be treated as output directory. With `find` you can add multiple `-not -name "Name"` arguments.

Comment: I see, cool! what if instead of being named "FolderA" and "FolderB" would be just "A" and "B"? Maybe changing "Folder*" with "A && B"?

Comment: You could either use [finds logical OR](https://arkit.co.in/find-command-logical-and-or-and-not-examples/) or the method with AND which I've provided in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm checking the code but it doesn't seem to work with me. 

The Zip contains every PDF I have in 2022, not just the ones in the months I wanted 

Comment: @Alberto You have never specified that there are pdf files in other directories than the ones with month names. Again: the script will find every PDF in every subdirectory and move the found files **two directories up**. That will of course only work if the directory structure is exactly as you've specified. If there are pdf files in directories other than the ones with month names, the output will be a mess.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I'll try to do it using your code as a basis, thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: @Alberto See my recent edit. It should also account for that case.

Comment: Thanks! I found a solution (I edited my original post) but thanks a lot for your work!

PS: seems like I get an error on line 8 because of the "*" instead of being called as the folder